# Not able to retrieve data of a single row in room database by selecting it

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, android-room

Main Activity

```
myRoomDatabase3 = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),MyRoomDatabase.class,"messagedb3").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().allowMainThreadQueries().build();

Message message4 = new Message();
            message4.setTime("14:10");
            message4.setContactName("Deepika");
            message4.setDate("02-12-2018");
            message4.setMsg("HI");

            MainActivity.myRoomDatabase3.myDao().addMessage(message4);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Message added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My MyDao interface code:-

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;

@Dao
public interface MyDao {

@Insert
public void addMessage(Message message);

@Query("SELECT * FROM messages3 WHERE message_date LIKE :givenDate AND "  + "message_time LIKE :givenTime LIMIT 1")
public Message getMessageInfo(String givenDate,String givenTime);
```

}

My Message class :-

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "messages3")
public class Message {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_date")
private String date;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_time")
private String time;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_contactName")
private String contactName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_msg")
private String msg;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getContactName() {
    return contactName;
}

public void setContactName(String contactName) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg= msg;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Trying to retrieve data from one row of database whose Date and Time is as given:-

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(Calendar.YEAR,2018);
    calender.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 02);
    SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String Date = simpledateformat.format(calender.getTime());

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
    SimpleDateFormat simpletimeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String Time = simpletimeformat.format(cal.getTime());

    Message message = MainActivity.myRoomDatabase3.myDao().getMessageInfo(Date,Time);

    String contactName = (message==null) ? "No data found" : message.getContactName();
    String text = (message == null) ? "No data found" : message.getMsg();
```

My Room Database class:-

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;


@Database(entities = {Message.class},version = 12,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract MyDao myDao();

}
```

My build.gradle file:-

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

Dependencies-

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
}
```

How to remove error?What is wrong?How to read a single row of data by searching it from date and time field?

I have added the entire code that I am using.Please please tell me something is wrong.I am stuck on this for 2-3 days.Something has to be wrong.What is it?
Why query is returning null?

Comment: It stopped working again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it , it is a completely stupid mistake.
When I am entering info into the database , I am entering the time as 14:10 but when I am trying to access it, I am using the time format "hh:mm" instead of "HH:mm" so I am trying to find the column having time as 02:10 instead of 14:10. These are two different values and hence null is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't returning anything. So message is null. You need to ensure that your query returns something or better yet, add code to handle the situation when nothing is found as that seems like a reasonable possible state.

A debugger could give the same answer a lot quicker than SO.

This will avoid the NullPointerException:

```
String text = (message == null) ? “No data found.” : message.getMsg();
```

Comment: How  to ensure that your query returns something

Comment: Put data in your database that satisfies your where clause or change your query. I can't give you a specific answer because I don't know your app's business logic.

Comment: Is there a need to implement myDao interface and define the getMessageInfo() method?

Comment: No. Spring is doing that for you. It’s your job to make sure the data is in the database or that you’re guarding against nulls in the calling code.

Comment: It had started working but then I created another project in android studio and copied the code in it as I wanted to do changes to the original code but now both the projects again started returning null when getMsg() is called .What to do?

Comment: It’s the same answer as before. Use your debugger and make sure you have data in your database.

Comment: It is giving correct result when app is running in background but returning null if the app is closed and reopened. Does room database get destroyed if app is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as only single record of Message then use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_date= :givenDate AND message_time= :givenTime LIMIT 1
```

Now, it will bind the query result to provided Message Object.

Comment: It had started working but then I created another project in android studio and copied the code in it as I wanted to do changes to the original code but now both the projects again started returning null when getMsg() is called .What to do?

Comment: Actually, the results you are getting are based on the data which is available in your device. So, do one thing, first keep the appropriate data which will satisfy your query and then try to check for null over there.

Comment: I tried to simply add some data and retrieve it using room and even that isn't working.

Comment: It is giving correct result when app is running in background but returning null if the app is closed and reopened. Does room database get destroyed if app is destroyed?